# How to flush or update cache for page by id in TYPO3

Tags: caching, typo3, typo3-8.x

I need to flush a cache for a specific page from TYPO3 version 8 backend in the Extension from my Controller. I found a solution for flushing all caches but this is the last option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Cache\CacheManager::class)
    ->flushCachesInGroupByTags('pages', [ 'pageId_'.$id ]);`

Answer (score 3):

The core handles the page cache clear using the DataHandler;

See: \TYPO3\CMS\Recordlist\RecordList::clearCache

```
/**
 * Clears page cache for the given page id, $this->id
 */
public function clearCache(int $pageId)
{
    $tce = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(DataHandler::class);
    $tce->start([], []);
    $tce->clear_cacheCmd($pageId);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try too. What is the difference between this two solutions?

Comment: The other solution uses the internal logic from the `DataHandler` (tag naming scheme). The `DataHandler` internally uses the `CacheManager` too.

Answer (score 3):

From within controller context (as asked..)

```
$this->cacheService->clearPageCache([$pageIds]);
```

This call includes the marked answer above.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry i cannot comment directly to the answer from Benjamin.
The second solution with DataHandler only works in backend context. If you want to clear the cache from your frontend plugin, you must use the marked answer.